# Neovim Configuration Steps after Installation

Tags: neovim

How do you config a terminal and IDE using NEOVIM after `brew install neovim` and the editor being Globally Available

- please do add your steps for the terminal on os~x if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean setting neovim as default Editor?

write following two command in your ~/.bashrc if using bash shell OR in ~/.zshrc

```
export EDITOR=nvim
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

If you re asking about where to start in terms of plugins for web development you can take a look at:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-guide-to-modern-web-development-with-neo-vim-333f7efbf8e2/

Comment: great. If my comment answered your question would you mind marking it as answere and giving it a vote ?